# How do you remove a Carrier / Bryant Infinity thermostat control from the wall?

Tags: hvac, thermostat

I have a Carrier Infinity system with model # SYSTXCCUID01-V thermostat/control. I need to temporarily remove it from the wall.

I found a diagram of how to install it:

[image]

[image]

([diagram source](https://www.utcccs-cdn.com/hvac/docs/1009/Public/0C/UID01-06SI.pdf))

I do not know how to release the interlocking tabs. It feels very tight and I don't want to break it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really will just pull straight off. (Just did it!)  No tools required. It feels tight but it seems designed to mount on/off this way.

(Encouraged to try that [by this post](https://www.justanswer.com/hvac/a9mc3-carrier-infinity-system-model-systxccuid01-v.html)).

Answer (score 3):

I had a reasonably new Bryant model. I found that by pulling firmly on the top right I was able to open a gap in the top middle just wide enough to get a butter knife in and bingo it pulls away easily from the right side.

Answer (score 2):

My advice is to gently pull straight out. I did it but I was not sure due to the difficulty of the release. Secondly, I would not ever buy an AC system that would only work with a special Thermostat! A replacement for my Infinity by Carrier is $960.00 (not customer friendly). The only reason my Thermostat is a problem is that the AC button broke. Otherwise if I remove the face and manually switch between Air and Heat- I can get by.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I tried to pry the thermostat from the back panel with screwdrivers with no luck. I was concerned that the plastic parts would break. Finally I tried a method that worked well. I used my finger tips on top of the thermostat to push opposite directions on the thermostat and the back mounting plate. It came apart quickly.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here.

Answer (score 1):

Careful, these 2 pieces will come apart, but in my case, the drywall anchors gave up first. Then a medium screwdriver was needed, but it wasn't tough. More mad about the drywall anchors.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.

Answer (score 0):

Yep first generation split /pull apart at the center seam.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. If you'll take a couple of minutes to [take the tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) and read the help center, you'll note that this is a Question & Answer board, not your run-of-the-internet discussion forum.

Answer (score 0):

I have a SYSTXCCUID01-B. Could not pull it off by hand. I inserted a car trim remover (plastic spudger) and pried from the top (between front and base plate), the top came off easily. Then pried from the bottom, the bottom came off easily.